# Gesture (swipe) listener won't work for any widget but a Button

Tags: android

I've got a swipe listener, based on SimpleOnGestureListener that works very well, as long as I attach it to a button like so:

```
final GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(MyGestureListener());
View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        if(detector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
     }
};

findViewById(R.id.widget).setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

However, if I change "widget" to something other than a Button, like a LinearLayout or a TextView, it no longer works.  Is there something I have to do to make it work with other widgets?

Comment: This may seem like a silly question, but you have implemented the "onFling" event somewhere, right? I'd also recommend putting in a few log statements to see what is and is not firing (in onTouch and onFling for example). If that still doesn't help there are a few examples floating about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection/938657#938657

Comment: onTouch gets called, but onFling only gets called when it's a button.  It's the weirdest thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel dumb, but I got it working by calling `myTextView.setClickable(true)`